# Trouble understanding UI-Router and nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm setting up an AngularJS app using Angular UI Router using states.

In my app there are multiple pages, and two of them have a tabbed view. So I'm using nested views to display the pages that have tabs.

The problem is, when I navigate to a page with tabs, the back button does not appear in the header like it does when you navigate to a normal page.

I'm having trouble understanding why not. The tabbed view state might be abstract, but the first tab that is loaded isn't. So shouldn't the back button simply appear?

I've set up this Plunkr to demonstrate what I mean:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jKII2S3uEnEOVDy9WBA2

Comment: The title is misleading , the `ui-router` works fine. The problem is with `ionic-framework`

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my understanding Ionic used a base implementation of UI Router, and so this would be applicable to all ui-router implementations. Can you confirm this is a bug within ionic? Confirmation would allow me to pursue this on the proper channels.

Comment: I confirm it's ionic problem . The whole `nav-bar` (with the back button) is part of the `ionic-framework` which happens to use ui-router.

Comment: Thank you @IlanFrumer. I will take it up with them.

Comment: Yes this is an Ionic Framework specific question. Ionic uses Angular UI Router, but has its own navView directive to handle keeping track of navigation history and transition between views.